# Cosmos DB Indexing Policy - Overlap?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have been assigned to work on an existing Cosmos DB implementation. The indexing policy does not seem to make sense at first glance. I understand that "/*" is supposed to be "root and all paths under it". So, why would someone make a policy like this?

```
"includedPaths": [
    {
        "path": "/*"
    },
    {
        "path": "/foo/?"
    },
    {
        "path": "/bar/?"
    }
]
```

In this case, "foo" and "bar" are legitimate attributes. However, I don't understand why they are specified explicitly, when "/*" is already present.

Ideas?

Comment: Where did you seen this configuration of indexing policy?

Comment: @JayGong It's the "includedPaths" attribute of the indexing policy of the Cosmos container. What is your question about it?

Comment: Yes, this indexing policy makes no sense.